# Retain leading zero(s) after SPLIT function (google-apps-script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a column that contains cells with numbers and/or numbers separated by commas.
Such as:

123, 456

987

321,5439,807

2024, 007,0193

I have a procedure that SPLITS and TRANSPOSES those cells based on commas:
(that portion of the procedure is below)

```
var lastRow = ss.getDataRange().getNumRows();
var srcRange = ss.getRange(lastRow,2);
var splitCell = '=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(' + srcRange.getA1Notation() + ',","))'; 
ss.getRange(lastRow,7).setFormula(splitCell);
```

The problem that I encounter is when one of the numbers contains a leading zero(s).
So in other words, this...

**2024, 007,0193**

becomes this...

**2024**

**7**

**193**

The worksheet is formatted as text, so it's the SPLIT that seems to be interpreting and converting the **007** and the **0193** into integers of **7** and **193**.

So how do I retain the leading zero(s) on the SPLIT side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try substituting the line:

```
var splitCell = '=arrayformula(transpose(substitute(split(substitute(' + srcRange.getA1Notation() + ',0,"#"),","),"#",0)))';
```

Comment: Yes indeed. That did the trick! I've actually used SUBSTITUTE before in Excel, but it never even occurred to me as an option with this. Until just recently SPLIT was unfamiliar to me so, I don't have enough knowledge or experience to get a feel for how it responds or how to control it's behavior. So thank you for bringing some insight (and a solution!) to this. It's very much appreciated!